# Jest doesn't await Set operations?

Tags: node.js, csv, jestjs

I am writing a test in Node via Jest in which I read a bunch of CSV files, parse a specific column, put it into a set and then validate a counter against the set to determine if there are duplicates.

However, the operation of parsing CSV values to the set it quite lengthy(3-4 minutes). Jest, however, does not wait for this: It just passes the test immediately.

Sample code:

```
describe('Test that all values are unique', () => {
    let validationCounter = 0
    const validationSet = new Set([])
    it('Read all csv files', () => {
        for (const number of dirsToCheck.keys()) {
            const baseDest = baseDir + "/something" + number
            Filehound.create()
            .ext('csv')
            .paths(baseDest)
            .find((err, csvFiles) => {
                if (err) {
                    return console.error("handle err", err)
                } else {
                    for (file of csvFiles) {
                        csv({
                            flatKeys: true,
                        })
                        .fromFile(file)
                        .on("json", (jsonObj) => {
                            const designatedValue = Object.values(jsonObj).toString().split(';')[2]
                            validationSet.add(designatedValue)
                            validationCounter++
                            console.log(designatedValue) // Will make everything "hang" until this is finished, if logged
                        })
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    })
    it('Validate array counter to the unique set', () =>{
        console.log(validationCounter) // Returns 0?
        console.log(validationSet.size) // Also 0?
        expect(uniqueVurderingsejendomsIds.size).toBe(validationCounter); // Somehow passes?
    })
});
```

If I `console.log(designatedValue)`, it will keep going for the entire four minutes and then exit once it's finished adding them to the set - without running the test.

If I remove this console.log statement, Jest will simply pass the overall test suite almost instantly(2 seconds)

What's happening, why doesn't Jest wait for this operation? It passes all tests instantly, and then Jest hangs without exiting. It is very strange behavior.

Answer (score 0):

It won't wait automatically.

You need to *signal* to your test to wait if you're doing any asynchronous operations, otherwise the test assumes synchronous code, "rushes" through it, finds no errors and considers it a success.

This is done by specifying a `done` argument in the `test` callback and then calling that argument when you're actually done with your async processing.

From [Jest: Testing Asynchronous Code](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/asynchronous.html):

> There is an alternate form of test that fixes this. Instead of putting the test in a function with an empty argument, use a single argument called done. Jest will wait until the done callback is called before finishing the test.

```
describe('fetchData', () => {
  it('callback with peanut butter', done => {
    fetchData((err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        // calling `done` with an argument assumes an error
        // and fails the test
        return done(err)
      }

      expect(result).toBe('peanut butter')
      done()
    })
  })
})

function fetchData(cb) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    cb(null, 'peanut butter')
  }, 200)
}
```

Before you attempt this, make sure you have the *latest* version of Jest. There [used to be a bug](https://github.com/facebook/jest/pull/4669) in Jest that results in timeouts.

Comment: I am now really certain how to implement this: Should I use `test` instead of `describe`? How should the `it` modules be structured? What does `fetchData` represent in your example?

Comment: No, you can just use `it('should do x', done => ...`). `fetchData` is just an asynchronous operation that takes a callback. Let me re-write it to be more clear.

Comment: Getting `Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout` but my process isn't really async? So I don't understand how this method would work.

Comment: You are using an older version of Jest. Run `$ npm uninstall -g jest` and `$ npm install -g jest` again. There is a [bug/strange behaviour](https://github.com/facebook/jest/pull/4669) in older versions of Jest.

Comment: No change. `jest --version >> v22.4.2`. Still get the timeout error.

Comment: Yes it works. The issue, I guess, is with my function: However, is it not async(and, it really can't be, nor do I want it to)?

Comment: Your `find((err, csvFiles) => ...)` method is async, judging from the callback pattern used there. Make sure you are eventually reaching the part of your code that calls `done`.

Comment: Hmm, perhaps; where would you put the `await` value in the above, though? I don't see it..

Comment: Your code is not using any `Promises` nor `async` Functions. What are you expecting to `await`?

Comment: Ok, let me rephrase: I made the function `async function runData()` with the for loop of the keys etc in it, and run it with your logic. The behavior is the same, it throws the timeout error.

Comment: There is no `runData` function anywhere. I'm having a strong suspicion you are abusing `async/await` to begin with.

Comment: No, I created it to follow your suggested pattern?

Comment: Well where is it? I can't see it so I can't help you. Furthermore do you know how `async/await` works or are you just throwing stuff on the wall and checking what sticks? No offence, honest question.

Comment: In the `describe` scope. And no, the done() is never reached because the code, as before, reads the csv files?

Comment: Ok, so my answer focuses on how to deal with asynchronous operations that use callbacks (which your OP uses), not `async/await`. Tests that use `async` functions are implemented somehow differently.

Comment: In that case, I don't really see how your example applies to my sample code, but perhaps we're speaking past each other

Comment: Perhaps. I'll leave the answer on as it might help others. Feel free to downvote if you are convinced I'm completely missing your point.

Comment: The code, from your example, would behave the exact same: The `done()` is never reached before it either times out, or hangs

Comment: Does my example code pass as green when you run it?

Comment: Yes. But it has nothing to do with my problem, and doesn't bind the properties of which I assign and intent to compare together.

Comment: Are you aware that my `fetchData` is just a placeholder function, meant to simulate an asynchronous operation? Do you know what asynchronous operations are and how they work with their callbacks etc?

Comment: Yes. If you do the same with my code, the result would be as before - hanging, then throws timeout error. The execution remains the same.

Comment: In that case you have a problem with your code. Fix it so it terminates (reaches `done`). Makes sense? If you never call `done` it will eventually timeout.

Comment: If you read my original problem, it will do the operations if each iteration is `console.log`'ed. If not, it exits instantly and passes.

Comment: Fair enough - I'll leave this for someone else to answer. I've answered part of your answer; which is how to make Jest wait for async operations. Someone else might be able to help you with your original code.